# Identifying where selected features are

Tags: arcmap, attribute-table, arcgis-10.7, select

I am able to select the features from the attribute table but my data is so small that I am unable to identify where the selected features are. The features selected are from a raster attribute table with the values OBJECTID, VALUE, AREA, and PERIMETER at the top.

I am trying to find out which provinces within China's Great Green Wall received the most forest gain/loss. I already have the figures for net gain/loss within the Great Green Wall boundary, just need to identify where it occurred within that boundary (thus my problem with selecting the features).

Comment: Perhaps convert selection to points.

Comment: Are you working with a vector? In the attribute table, right click on the selection and then zoom to selection

Comment: Can't you just "zoom to selected features"?